# Why is the answer marked 19.5?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion

> A star S is being orbited by a planet P such that the planet rotates around itself once every 0.1 earth days. It is observed that P completes 196 rotations around itself by the time it completes 1 revolution around S. If the planet's sense of rotation and revolution is in the same direction, its orbital period (in earth days) would be?

Intuitively, the answer should be 19.6, but its marked 19.5. Why?

*Edit: Okay so I guess the answer is somewhere connected to tidal locking, i.e. the planet (if it was not rotating) will automatically complete one rotation about its own axis by the time it completes one revolution. But is it necessary that tidal locking always happens. Why is it assumed that this rotation happens, can't the planet not rotate at all?*

Comment: I feel like the original question is phrased the wrong way for what it is trying to teach. It must also specify what the rotation of the planet about itself *is relative to*. Implicitly they seem to mean relative to $S$, so it would match one full day on that planet. But it could also mean relative to some fixed (distant) background, then the answer would be 19.6.

Comment: This is an olympiad question, not a homework question. I couldn't solve it, and couldn't find a better way to ask the answer. Why the downvotes?

Answer (score 2):

The question is very poorly phrased. The answer depends on whether $0.1$ Earth days is the length of the planet's sidereal day or its solar day (see [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sidereal_time)). The number of sidereal days in an orbital period is one more than the number of solar days. If there are $196$ sidereal days in one orbit then there are only $195$ solar days, and if one solar day is $0.1$ Earth days then the orbital period is $19.5$ earth days. But if one sidereal days is $0.1$ Earth days (which i think is the more natural interpretation of question) then the orbital period is $19.6$ Earth days.

Comment: So, in case of a planet, if the number of solar days (in one year) is X, the number of sidereal days will always be (X+1). So does that mean even if the planet rotates (X+1) times in a year, we will only see X days on average per year?

Comment: @VanshajVidyan that depends on the directions of rotation about its axis and revolution around its star.